# What word could I use to confront a friend who defends the behavior of a gossip?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I would like a word or a phrase to use to confront a "friend" who glosses over the harmful gossip of another "friend." I think she defends the gossip because the gossip is influential in town.

My friend says that she is being "objective." I want to tell her otherwise.

Comment: Look under [sycophant](http://thesaurus.com/browse/sycophant) in the thesaurus.

Answer (score 2):

**Apologist**. Although the word is usually used to defend a religious or political ideology, it is also used to defend the bad behavior of corporations, politicians, celebrities, and others who make the news.

Answer (score 1):

You could always concoct some offensively provocative terms yourself. e.g.,

- Rumour monger
- Gossip monger
- Gossip day-trader
- insecurities dealer
- insecure old prick
- a-hole
- ABC = assistant ballistics curator
- ABC = adjutant balls crusher
- compulsive personality disorder
- OCD

Comment: Let's not leave out the fairer sex - backstabbing be-yatch. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is in the comment posted by Matt. I take no credit for it but 'sycophant' really does seem to sum up exactly what you mean if you are trying to accuse said "friend" of defending the gossip only due to how influential the person is.